# Determine algebraically if the function $f(x) = x^2 + 4x$ is onto or not

Tags: calculus, functions, elementary-set-theory, quadratics

Determine algebraically if the function  $f(x) = x^2 + 4x$ is onto or not

I do not know how to approach this question, how should I go about it. How should I factor $x^2 + 4x$?

Comment: **Hint**: if you want to factor the function, note that $x \times x=x^2$. **Better hint**: are parabolas ever onto?

Comment: `onto` from what into what? It is important to include the definition of $f$. For example, if it's defined as $f : [0,1] \to [0,5]$ or  $f : \mathbb{R} \to [-4, \infty)$ then it *is* onto.

Comment: I don't see that factoring the polynomial will help you.  At least not directly.

Answer (score 1):

You should know [a method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) that symbolically allows you to calculate the solutions of the equation $$x^2+4x=y$$ in terms of $y$, and which also allows you to decide when such solutions exist in the real numbers. You should use it here.

Answer (score 1):

If the function is onto (onto what? the reals?)  then for every $y$ there is an $x$ such that $f(x) =x^2 + 4x = y$.

So $x^2 + 4x -y = 0$.  So $x = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{16 + 4y}}{2}$.

But if $y < -4$ then $16 + 4y < 0$ and there is no such real $x$.  So there are no $x$ so that $f(x) = y; y < -4$.

So $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is not onto.

*HOWEVER*

If $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow [-4, \infty)$ then $f$ is onto.

Or if $f: \mathbb C \rightarrow C$ then $f$ is onto.

Answer (score 0):

What they want you to do is to examine whether there can ever be an $x$ such that $x^2+4x=-10$ (i.e. solve that equation). Because if the function is onto, then there should be such an $x$. (Note: there is nothing really special about $-10$ here, other than being smaller than $-4$.)

Answer (score 0):

To say that $f$ is onto means that for all real numbers $b$, the equation $f(x) = b$ has a solution $x$. Thus, we ask does $x^2 + 4x = b$ always have solutions? The answer is given by the quadratic formula:
$$
x = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{16 +4b}}{2}.
$$
If $16 + 4b \ge 0$, then there is a solution $x$. However, we can see that some values of $b$ make $16 + 4b < 0$. That means that $x$ would have to be complex for $f(x) = b$. In other words, $f$ is not onto since for $b \lt -4$, there do not exist real numbers $x$ such that $f(x) = b$.

If you wanted to vet this with analytic geometry. The graph of $f$ is an upward-facing parabola. Parabolas have vertices, and the graph of an upward-facing parabola cannot "reach" points below the vertex, so our answer makes sense with what we know from analytic geometry.

Comment: I think you mean for $b < -4$.

Comment: @fleablood nice catch

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to factor the polynomial. I assume that the question is if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^2 +4x$ is onto.

This is not the case. There are a couple of ways to see this

1. From the graph you can see that you can draw a horizontal line that does not intersect the graph.
2. Maybe also from a graph you can guess a number (like $-10$ as suggested in another answer) $a$ such that $x^2 +4x = a$ does not have any solution. All you are trying to do is to find this $a$ such that the discriminant $4^2 - 4\cdot 1 \cdot (-a)$ is negative. That is, you need to find an $a$ such that $16 + 4a$ is negative. This shouldn't be too hard.
3. You can also appeal to the fact that all polynomials are *continuous* and so since the domain is the set of all real numbers and $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} x^2 + 4x = \infty$, the function will attain a minimal value. Hence there is a smallest value and so $x^2 + 4x$ can't be smaller than that. Hence the function is not onto.

Answer (score 0):

After [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) you can rewrite the given function as 
$$f(x) = (x^2+4x+4)-4 = (x+2)^2-4.$$
So you immediately see that $f(x)\ge -4$ for every real number $x$. This means that there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=-5$, the function is not [surjective (onto)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function).